# emberjs back key leaves some display from child route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

To see the problem, please run the following in browser by clicking the arrow shown in upper right corner of of output panel.

http://jsbin.com/uVORASe/4/edit?html,js,output

Click one of the links (either strategy-1 or strategy-2) to display output generated by the child template.  Then click back button on browser.  When the back button is clicked, browser shows the parent URL as expected.  But parts of the child display remains on screen.  This process repeats every time a child route is visited.  Why?  Going back to the parent route should just display strategy-1 and strategy-2 on the left side.

I don't think this is an Ember-Data issue because problem also happens when I tried Ember-Model.  I think use of the bootstrap classess has something to do with this.  For example, if I take away the bootstrap table-responsive class, Ember throws an error.

Any ideas to explain what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The close tag of your `<table>` tag is wrong. You are using `</table` the expected is `</table>`.

http://jsbin.com/UKONORI/1/edit

Comment: Marcio, thank you very much.  The program is actually quite a bit bigger than the sample I posted in JSBin.  I stared at it for hours trying to find something obvious like this but didn't, then spent more hours pairing it down to an example of manageable size and still didn't see it.  Guess just takes a pair of fresh eyes.  Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! In most of the time, big templates are a problem, and give these html problems. It's a good idea separate him in small pieces using {{render}} {{partial}} etc. More info here http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/